# AWS NAT instance as OpenVPN Client can't route instances behind it

Tags: iptables, amazon-web-services, openvpn, nat, amazon-ami

I have an Amazon AMI 2015.09 instance as a NAT server for my backend servers.

I have configured the OpenVPN client on this same box, the NAT server is able to talk to everything over VPN, all resources are available as expected.  But all the backend servers behind this NAT no longer can get internet access.  Once I take down the OpenVPN client on the NAT server, the instances behind it are able to get online again.

Anything I could look at specifically with the NAT instance on AWS?  I don't know what I can provide when I know the VPN connection is functional between the client and the server, so I am assuming it could be routing/iptables rules on the NAT box not forwarding as expected.

the NAT server does see traffic (`tcpdump -n not port 22`) from the instances behind it, but I am not quite sure how it's handling that traffic.

Any suggestions as to why this is happening, and how to resolve it would be great.

EDIT: As this is a functional NAT server, the src/dst checks are disabled in the ec2 instance.

EDIT2:

Output with OpenVPN client turned off:

```
[root@ip-10-0-0-39 ~]# ip route  list table all
default via 10.0.0.1 dev eth0 
10.0.0.0/24 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.0.0.39 
169.254.169.254 dev eth0 
broadcast 10.0.0.0 dev eth0  table local  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.0.0.39 
local 10.0.0.39 dev eth0  table local  proto kernel  scope host  src 10.0.0.39 
broadcast 10.0.0.255 dev eth0  table local  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.0.0.39 
broadcast 127.0.0.0 dev lo  table local  proto kernel  scope link  src 127.0.0.1 
local 127.0.0.0/8 dev lo  table local  proto kernel  scope host  src 127.0.0.1 
local 127.0.0.1 dev lo  table local  proto kernel  scope host  src 127.0.0.1 
broadcast 127.255.255.255 dev lo  table local  proto kernel  scope link  src 127.0.0.1 
unreachable ::/96 dev lo  metric 1024  error -101
unreachable ::ffff:0.0.0.0/96 dev lo  metric 1024  error -101
unreachable 2002:a00::/24 dev lo  metric 1024  error -101
unreachable 2002:7f00::/24 dev lo  metric 1024  error -101
unreachable 2002:a9fe::/32 dev lo  metric 1024  error -101
unreachable 2002:ac10::/28 dev lo  metric 1024  error -101
unreachable 2002:c0a8::/32 dev lo  metric 1024  error -101
unreachable 2002:e000::/19 dev lo  metric 1024  error -101
unreachable 3ffe:ffff::/32 dev lo  metric 1024  error -101
fe80::/64 dev eth0  proto kernel  metric 256 
unreachable default dev lo  table unspec  proto kernel  metric 4294967295  error -101
local ::1 dev lo  table local  proto none  metric 0 
local fe80::1074:88ff:fe94:45c7 dev lo  table local  proto none  metric 0 
ff00::/8 dev eth0  table local  metric 256 
unreachable default dev lo  table unspec  proto kernel  metric 4294967295  error -101
```

Output with OpenVPN client turned on:

```
[root@ip-10-0-0-39 ~]# ip route  list table all
default via 10.0.0.1 dev eth0 
10.0.0.0/24 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.0.0.39 
10.0.0.0/23 via 10.172.0.1 dev tun0 
10.0.8.0/24 via 10.172.0.1 dev tun0 
10.0.100.0/22 via 10.172.0.1 dev tun0 
10.10.10.0/24 via 10.172.0.1 dev tun0 
10.100.100.0/24 via 10.172.0.1 dev tun0 
10.101.101.0/24 via 10.172.0.1 dev tun0 
10.172.0.0/16 via 10.172.0.1 dev tun0 
10.172.0.1 dev tun0  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.172.23.253 
10.200.0.0/16 via 10.172.0.1 dev tun0 
169.254.169.254 dev eth0 
172.23.0.0/16 via 10.172.0.1 dev tun0 
172.24.0.0/16 via 10.172.0.1 dev tun0 
broadcast 10.0.0.0 dev eth0  table local  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.0.0.39 
local 10.0.0.39 dev eth0  table local  proto kernel  scope host  src 10.0.0.39 
broadcast 10.0.0.255 dev eth0  table local  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.0.0.39 
local 10.172.23.253 dev tun0  table local  proto kernel  scope host  src 10.172.23.253 
broadcast 127.0.0.0 dev lo  table local  proto kernel  scope link  src 127.0.0.1 
local 127.0.0.0/8 dev lo  table local  proto kernel  scope host  src 127.0.0.1 
local 127.0.0.1 dev lo  table local  proto kernel  scope host  src 127.0.0.1 
broadcast 127.255.255.255 dev lo  table local  proto kernel  scope link  src 127.0.0.1 
unreachable ::/96 dev lo  metric 1024  error -101
unreachable ::ffff:0.0.0.0/96 dev lo  metric 1024  error -101
unreachable 2002:a00::/24 dev lo  metric 1024  error -101
unreachable 2002:7f00::/24 dev lo  metric 1024  error -101
unreachable 2002:a9fe::/32 dev lo  metric 1024  error -101
unreachable 2002:ac10::/28 dev lo  metric 1024  error -101
unreachable 2002:c0a8::/32 dev lo  metric 1024  error -101
unreachable 2002:e000::/19 dev lo  metric 1024  error -101
unreachable 3ffe:ffff::/32 dev lo  metric 1024  error -101
fe80::/64 dev eth0  proto kernel  metric 256 
unreachable default dev lo  table unspec  proto kernel  metric 4294967295  error -101
local ::1 dev lo  table local  proto none  metric 0 
local fe80::1074:88ff:fe94:45c7 dev lo  table local  proto none  metric 0 
ff00::/8 dev eth0  table local  metric 256 
unreachable default dev lo  table unspec  proto kernel  metric 4294967295  error -101
```

This doesn't seem like an issue of split tunnel, as there is only one interface, and the default traffic is still good.

The NAT clients behind it are in the 10.0.1.0/24 space, which falls on the 10.0.0.0/23 space to route through tun0.  What else could I be missing?

output of ifconfig:

```
[root@ip-10-0-0-39 ~]# ifconfig -a
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 12:74:88:94:45:C7  
          inet addr:10.0.0.39  Bcast:10.0.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::1074:88ff:fe94:45c7/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:3214673 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:2918238 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:948912082 (904.9 MiB)  TX bytes:770701301 (734.9 MiB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 b)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 b)
```

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like your OpenVPN server is not set up for split tunneling. As such, the server's default gateway is changing to point through the VPN tunnel when the client is running. You'll need to enable split tunneling so this doesn't happen.

Comment: "Server's default gateway" ?  The OpenVPN server is running, and has over 200 clients and their networks routed through it.  The AWS VPN Client connects fine, and can traverse the VPN network easily, including other VPN client networks:

AWS Client -> VPN Server -> other VPN locations

The problem is that the backend servers behind the AWS VPN Client:

Backend01 -> AWS VPN Client -> VPN Server

This connection never works, but the moment I take down the VPN Client on the AWS, Backend01 can reach the internet.


My AWS VPN Client is also the nat router for Backend01